# Graphics problem and compatible graphics card

Tags: gaming, graphics-cards, desktop, pc

I suspect that my video card burned after upgrading the RAM from 1gb to 2gb. The screen has a purple tint. When I downgraded it to 1gb, the purple tint is still there. What could be the problem here? And I am planning to change my GPU. What should I buy?

PC Specs:
From system properties:

- Windows 8.1 Pro
- Intel Core 2 Duo CPU E7500 @ 2.93 GHz 2.94 GHz
- 2GB RAM
- 32-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

From DxDiag
Display Tab:

- Intel G41 Express Chipset
- BenQ GL950A Monitor

Comment: If you re-word this question to focus on the "What should I buy" part, this could be re-opened. Even then, you would have to add more details to it (price, desired specs, what you are planning on using it for, what it is going into, etc.)